# How to validate @mydomain.com on email field

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form with email field. The email field validation is ready but, I need now that this field allow only `@mydomain.com` not gmail, hotmail.com or any other...

I need allow only my domain.
How I can do this?

Comment: I think the pattern attribute for input fields is what you are searching for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the string of the email.

Then, split the email address by using the following code.

```
var email = $("#email_id").val();
var split_email = email.split('@');
```

Finally, you can just compare the domain.

```
var your_domain = "domain.com";
if(your_domain === split_email[1]){
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: No problem =) @user3230164

Answer (score 1):

Use regex in `pattern` attribute of input.

```html
<form>
    <input type="email" pattern=".*@mydomain.com" required />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want users to give email addresses from external domains, just don't allow it in the first place.

```
<label for="username">What is your @mydomain email address</label><br />
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />@mydomain.com
```